In what theory consistency proofs take place?
I am reading Kenneth Kunnen's Set Theory and had this question.
For instance, on Page 113 Lemma 2.3 states that: Assume $S,T$ are set of sentences in the language of set theory, and assume that for some class $M$, we can prove from $T$ that $M$ is a model of $S$. Then $Con(T)\rightarrow Con(S)$.
My question is that in which theory does the implication hold; is it $T\vdash Con(T)\rightarrow Con(S)$?
Here is how Kenneth Kunnen proves the Lemma: Assuming $S$ is inconsistent, we can prove a contradiction (say $\varphi$) from $S$. Then since $T$ proves $M$ is a model of $S$, we also get $T\vdash \varphi^M$. This shows that $T$ is inconsistent.
All the above argument makes sense to me, but I can't think of this being done within a formal proof system.
This same question arises when trying to understand the fact $ZF-Reg\vdash Con(ZF-Reg)\rightarrow Con(ZF)$ where $Reg$ is the axiom of foundation. All the proofs I have searched so far argues by relying on the completeness theorem or goes by contrapositive. But the completeness theorem uses AC, so I don't think an argument using the completeness theorem can be done within $ZF-Reg$.
The argument by contrapositive goes as follows: Assuming that $ZF$ is inconsistent, there are $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n$ of $ZF$ which proves $\forall x(x\neq x)$. Since $ZF-Reg\vdash \varphi^{WF}$ for any $\varphi$ of $ZF$, we can conclude that $ZF-Reg\vdash [(\forall x)(x\neq x)]^{WF}$. So $ZF-Reg$ is inconsistent.
Here, if we are trying to work within a formal proof system, how do we plot out $\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n$? (Doesn't $\neg Con(T)$ say "there exists a proof from $T$ which proves a contradiction", so that we can't plot out exactly which axioms of $T$ prove a contradiction inside a proof system?). And even after getting $ZF-Reg\vdash [(\forall x)(x\neq x)]^{WF}$, I understand that this implies $ZF-Reg$ is inconsistent, but I think our goal was to prove $\neg Con(ZF-Reg)$?
I assume I have misunderstandings on many places, so I appreciate any help with fixing them!

The completeness theorem does not require AC here, since the language is countable.

$\mathrm{Con(ZF-Reg)}\rightarrow\mathrm{Con(ZF)}$ is essentially a number theoretic statement, and is provable in very weak systems. Working in $\mathsf{ZF-Reg}$ would be an overkill (note that I use $\mathsf{ZF-Reg}$ for the "metatheory" and $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}$ for the "target theory"; it's probably more standard to use $\ulcorner\mathsf{ZF-Reg}\urcorner$ for the target theory).
The formalist viewpoint may be helpful for understanding these issues. All we are really doing is fiddling around with formulas, i.e. strings of symbols, which are finite in nature, and we can just reason about them using "common sense". If you really want to work in some formal system, $\mathsf{PRA}$ (Primitive Recursive Arithmetic) is probably enough; use $\mathsf{PA}$ (Peano Arithmetic) if you want to be safe, or if you like me don't quite understand the definition of $\mathsf{PRA}$...
The key ingredient for showing $\mathrm{Con(ZF-Reg)}\rightarrow\mathrm{Con(ZF)}$ is that whenever $\mathrm{ZF}\vdash\varphi$ for a sentence $\varphi$, we have $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}\vdash\varphi^{WF}$, where $\varphi^{WF}$ is the relativization defined by recursively replacing $\forall x$ with $\forall x\in WF$, and $x\in WF$ is a shorthand for some complicated formula. This is proved by the standard technique "induction on length of formal proof", which is also used to prove the deduction theorem in first order logic. To facilitate the induction, we actually need a version that also handles formula with free variables:

Theorem: $\mathrm{ZF}\vdash\varphi$ implies $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}\vdash\forall x_1\in WF\cdots\forall x_m\in WF\ \varphi^{WF}$, where $x_1,\dots,x_m$ are all the free variables in $\varphi$.

Note that it's not true that $\mathrm{ZF}\vdash\varphi$ implies $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}\vdash\varphi^{WF}$ for arbitrary formulas: $\mathrm{ZF}\vdash x\in WF$ but certainly $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}\not\vdash x\in WF$.
If we use Hilbert's style proof system, $\mathrm{ZF}\vdash\varphi$ means there exists a sequence of formulas $\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n$ such that each of them is either a $\mathrm{ZF}$ axiom, a logical axiom or obtained from previous formulas using one of the two inference rules: modus ponens or  universal generalization, and the last formula $\varphi_n$ is $\varphi$. Then we prove by induction on $i\leq n$ that $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}\vdash\varphi_i^{WF}$; the proof is a bit tedious but doesn't use any smart tricks and is a nice exercise. For example:

If $\varphi_i$ is a $\mathrm{ZF}$ axiom (so in particular it's a sentence) then $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}\vdash\varphi_i^{WF}$, as desired; this is due to the fact that $WF$ is a class model of $\mathrm{ZF}$, which takes a separate proof.

If $\varphi_i$ is a logical axiom like $A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow A)$, then $\varphi_i^{WF}$ is $A^{WF}\rightarrow(B^{WF}\rightarrow A^{WF})$, also a logical axiom. Then $\forall x_1\cdots\forall x_m\ A^{WF}\rightarrow(B^{WF}\rightarrow A^{WF})$ is provable from $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}$, which implies $\forall x_1\in WF\cdots\forall x_m\in WF\ A^{WF}\rightarrow(B^{WF}\rightarrow A^{WF})$.

Suppose $\varphi_i=\forall x\varphi_j$ is obtained from $\varphi_j$ using universal generalization. If $x$ appears free in $\varphi_j$, then suppose $x,x_1,\dots,x_m$ are all the free variables in $\varphi_j$. By induction hypothesis we have $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}\vdash\forall x\in WF\forall x_1\in WF\cdots\forall x_m\in WF\ \varphi_j^{WF}$; this sentence is equivalent to $\forall x_1\in WF\cdots\forall x_m\in WF(\forall x\varphi_j)^{WF}$, which is exactly what we want. If $x$ does not appear free in $\varphi_j$, then again suppose the free variables in $\varphi_j$ are $x_1,\dots,x_m$. By induction hypothesis we have $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}\vdash\forall x_1\in WF\cdots\forall x_m\in WF\ \varphi_j^{WF}$. It is harmless to add a "silly universal quantification", so $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}\vdash\forall x\forall x_1\in WF\cdots\forall x_m\in WF\ \varphi_j^{WF}$, which implies $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}\vdash\forall x_1\in WF\cdots\forall x_m\in WF\ \varphi_i^{WF}$.

The modus ponens case is similar.


Now suppose $\lnot\mathrm{Con(ZF)}$, so $\mathrm{ZF}\vdash\forall x(x\neq x)$. Then $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}\vdash(\forall x(x\neq x))^{WF}$, but $(\forall x(x\neq x))^{WF}$ is by definition $\forall x(x\in WF\rightarrow x\neq x)$. Since $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}$ also proves that $WF$ is nonempty, we get $\mathrm{ZF-Reg}\vdash \exists x(x\neq x)$, namely $\lnot\mathrm{Con(ZF-Reg)}$.
I'm not sure what do you mean by "proof by completeness theorem". Completeness theorem says a consistent theory has a model. Are you thinking about the converse, namely if a theory has a model then it is consistent? That's called soundness theorem and does not rely on $\mathsf{AC}$. But you do need some basic set theory to discuss models, so this approach doesn't work in $\mathsf{PA}$.

For the first sentence of your third paragraph, did you mean that we have to prove $ZF-Ref\vdash \text{Prov}{ZF}(\varphi)\rightarrow\text{Prov}{ZF-Ref}(\varphi^{WF})$ for each $\varphi$ such that $ZF$ proves?

I'm not sure whether your last ZF refers to the metatheory or the target theory. In any case it should not be there. $\mathrm{Prov}{\mathrm{ZF}}(\varphi)\rightarrow\mathrm{Prov}{\mathrm{ZF-Reg}}(\varphi^{WF})$ is outright provable in weak systems like Peano Arithmetic, not to mention in $\mathsf{ZF-Reg}$

What are metatheory and target theory? And could you briefly describe how to prove $\text{Prov}{ZF}(\varphi)\rightarrow\text{Prov}{ZF-Reg}(\varphi^{WF})$? Do I consider a function which maps a ZF proof to a ZF-Reg proof?

@mathlearner98 Yes, there is a (very concrete procedure) to turn a ZF proof of $\varphi$ into a ZF-Reg proof of $\varphi^{WF}$; I have added some details. Looking at the procedure, you should be convinced that we are not using anything about infinite sets, but only using basic mathematical reasoning about finite strings of symbols, which can be coded into natural numbers (say by prime factorization).

@mathlearner98 So I would say the proof goes through in common sense; then common sense is my metatheory. It is certainly possible to formalize the proof in $\mathsf{PA}$, in which case $\mathsf{PA}$ is your metatheory. Target theory is the theory whose proofs you are studying, like ZF or ZF-Reg. You can choose your metatheory to be $\mathsf{ZF-Reg}$, but that's way too strong than necessary, and also you need to distinguish it from the target theory ZF-Reg. There are situations where the metatheory and target theory are the "same", like in second incompleteness theorem.

Though this is a quite a late catch-up question, for the Lemma 2.3 which asserts $Con(T)\rightarrow Con(S)$, this conclusion is also taking place inside ZF? And in general, for instance, when we are studying model theory, when we argue that $M\models \varphi$, I think what we argued was essentially $ZF\vdash "M\models \varphi"$. So I wonder if it is correct to say that: when we say $M\models\varphi$, it is essentially $ZF\vdash "M\models\varphi"$.

@mathlearner98 No it's taking place in common sense, or $\mathsf{PA}$ if you want. We are not really doing model theory because $M$ is a "class model". Although a class model is in many ways analogous to a set model, it is essentially a formula with one free variable. $x\in WF$ is such a formula, and $x\in L$ is another example. The key difference between set model and class model is that, for set model you can define the satisfaction relation $N\models_s\varphi$.

Formally you write down a formula $\mathrm{Sat}(N,\varphi,s)$ with three free varaibles $N$, $\varphi$, $s$: $N$ is a set model, $\varphi$ is a (suitably coded) formula, and $s$ is an assignment. For a class model $M$ you (in general) cannot do that (Tarski's undefinability of truth). So $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash``M\models\varphi''$ really means $\mathsf{ZF}\vdash\varphi^M$, where $\varphi^M$ is the relativization.
